# Select first interface with yq on YAML netplan file

Tags: yaml, yq, netplan

I'm trying to select the first interface with `yq` (the [Github mikefarah/yq version](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)) on /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml :

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      link-local: []
      addresses: [x.y.z.t/24]
      routes:
       - to: default
         via: x.y.z.1
    ens192:
      link-local: []
      addresses: [a.b.c.d/24]
  version: 2
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml | yq '.network.ethernets[0]'
null
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml | yq '.network.ethernets.ens*[0]'
null
null
```

How do I do that with `yq` ?

Comment: Please mention in your question, according to the [`yq` tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info), that you are using / asking for a solution with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) or the "Go implementation".

Comment: @pmf Hi, I'm using the mikefarah/yq version.

Answer (score 1):

`.network.ethernets` is an object having fields with keys (not an array having items with indices). Thus, it also has no order. But you can use `keys` to get an array of the keys, and use the first of them to access the field:

```bash
yq '.network.ethernets | .[keys | .[0]]' etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```

```yaml
link-local: []
addresses: [x.y.z.t/24]
routes:
  - to: default
    via: x.y.z.1
```